# How to add jwt authentication cookie in sveltekit application from golang API?

Tags: go, authentication, jwt, svelte, sveltekit

I know I can set cookies from **Sveltekit** , but I wanted to connect my database only with my **Golang** API,  I have all the cookie validation code written in **golang**, Now  how can I redirect all my requests in an external API